# ssh-agent doesn't accept passphrase on first load

Tags: ssh, macos, key-authentication, ssh-agent

When there is no ssh-agent process running, when I open my terminal, the ssh-agent is started and it asks me for my passphrase for my private key. Every time I try to enter it, I get an error: `Bad passphrase, try again for /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519:`. I don't change the content of my clipboard in between. After several failed tries, I just close the terminal window and reopen it again, and the prompt for my passphrase reappears, then I paste again the same passphrase (without copying it again) and it accepts it.
I've killed the ssh-agent processes several times to verify this, and the same behavior always happens. What is wrong with my ssh-agent? It is the default one on macOS.

Here is an alternative situation below.
In this case, after several failed attempts, I pressed `Ctrl+C`. The line `Starting ssh-agent ...` was printed and I did not even attempt to reopen the terminal window a second time to enter my passphrase. Instead, I tried to SSH into my website server in the same terminal session right away, expecting to be asked for my passphrase again. But instead of a prompt for a passphrase, the connection just succeeded, as if my passphrase had already been entered and accepted.

```
   ~  Enter passphrase for /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519: 0:03 
Bad passphrase, try again for /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519:
Bad passphrase, try again for /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519:
Bad passphrase, try again for /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519:
```

When I press `(Ctrl+C)`, the output below is printed:

```
Starting ssh-agent ...
user@users-mbp ~ % ssh website.com
Last login: Sat Jan 27 17:08:16 2024 from xx.xxx.xx.xxx
[user@website ~]$
```

Here is my ~/.ssh/config file content:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host website.com
  HostName xx.xxx.xx.xxx
  Port 1500
  User user
```

Comment: Just a general tip to get you started, try using the `ssh -v` switch and then inspecting both the ssh output and the `sshd` security log.